# React router dom v6 using useNevigation is not working with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I upgraded the REACT ROUTER DOM TO V6 from V5
I use REDUX and I have a general function called CHANGE ROUTE within the COMMON.ACTION
Until now I used the HISTORY.PUSH and after the update, I need to change it to USE NAVIGATE but every time I change it I get the following error

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

now I know that I break the hooks rules but I don't know why as changeRoute is a function
what I'm I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help

this is my APP that used Navigation component:

```
return (
        <Site onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}>
            <Navigation />
            <SnackbarContentWrapper/>
            <AppLevelComponents/>
        </Site>
    );
```

this is Navigation.js:

```
const Login = lazy(() => import("../../pages/login/Login"));

const Navigation = () => {
    const fallback = <WithFullScreenLayout><Loader/></WithFullScreenLayout>;
    return (
        <Suspense fallback={fallback}>
            <Routes>
                <Route  path="/login" element={<Login />}/>
               </Routes>

        </Suspense>
    )
};

export default Navigation;
```

this is my chagnRoute function in common.action:

```
export const changeRoute = (route) => (dispatch) => {
    const nav = useNavigate();
    commonService.changeRoute(`${window.location.pathname}${window.location.search}`);
    if (route !== '' && route !== '/') { // to prevent looping
        nav(route);
    }

    dispatch({
        type: CHANGE_ROUTE,
        payload: route
    });
};
```

this is how I used it in other components:

```
dispatch(changeRoute("/blabla"))
```

before the upgrade to router dom v6 its works like this in commom.action and evreything works OK:

```
export const changeRoute = (route) => (dispatch) => {
    const nav = useNavigate();
    commonService.changeRoute(`${window.location.pathname}${window.location.search}`);
    if (route !== '' && route !== '/') { // to prevent looping
        history.push(route);
    }

    dispatch({
        type: CHANGE_ROUTE,
        payload: route
    });
};
```

Comment: The error is correct: you can only use hooks in components. RR6 doesn't support this use case, you need to navigate in components not actions.

Comment: there is no other solution? as if I do it as you say I'll have to go through all the components in my project.
router dom v6 is not supported with redux? @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 0):

Your `changeRoute` is a javascript function, not a React function component

The rules of hooks say: Only Call Hooks from **React Functions**
Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions.

This means you can't call `useNavigate` inside `changeRoute`

Instead, you can pass `nav` to `changeRoute` as a parameter like this

```
dispatch(changeRoute("/blabla", useNavigation()))
```

But you have to make sure to call this dispatch only inside React function components